# How do I fix this? Relation Error - TypeError: Cannot read property - Creating new record: (Error)

Tags: google-app-maker

A short description of the issue:

I can't make a new page, 2 data source relation function in my app (which has similar existing pages with relations that work). The new relation always produces the following error on the parent table:

*E Fri Nov 08 08:10:55 GMT-700 2019
TypeError: Cannot read property "EkYkTNJF93VWDxnS7Gi1OIIBSsHXTZ7H" from null.
E Fri Nov 08 08:10:55 GMT-700 2019
Creating new record: (Error) : Cannot read property "EkYkTNJF93VWDxnS7Gi1OIIBSsHXTZ7H" from null.
at Apex_Office_Time.Table1Panel.Table1.Button1.onClick:1:19
E Fri Nov 08 08:10:55 GMT-700 2019
Creating new record failed.*

I I am always able to produce the error even when I start a new app from a blank template. The error will occur & not show the new record. Yet if I refresh, the record will be there. Existing apps with similar relations always work.

[001 Here is the data source relation between the 2 data sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGrWS.jpg)

[Here is a newly set up Google cloud SQL data source "Apex_Office_Time"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnI7V.jpg)

[Here is the Second Data source "Apex_Office_Time_Details"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4cIi.jpg)

[Here Is the Page "Apex_Office_Time" which contains a table. The blue + button should create a new item on the table. It does when there is no relation between the data sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoedD.jpg)

[Here is a shot that of the page that show the data source for the table is related to "Apex_Office_Time"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOdn2.jpg)

[Here is the generated preview before I hit the + button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APwrP.jpg)

[Here is the generated preview after I hit the + button & complete with error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPwaW.jpg)

[Here is the generated preview after I hit the + button, and after I manually hit the refresh button on my browser. I get the same results in Chrome, Firefox, & MS Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6pNp.jpg)

Further points of note:

- When I set up a table that generates items for the "many" side of the relationship "Apex_Office_Time_Details",  new items for this table are created without issue.
- I just added a third data source to the mix "Apex_Office_Test". I then made "Apex_Office_Time_Details" to "Apex_Office_Test" a one to Many relation. I then tested to see if I could create items in "Apex_Office_Time_Details" without issue as before. I was successful. I then tested to see if I could create items in "Apex_Office_Test". I was successful. I then deleted the "Apex_Office_Time" data source and retested the other 2 tables and their data sources. I was successful. It seems very odd, but its working. I am going to continue testing based on this line.
- Success! Evidently there is a minimum length for the names in data sources. The number fields "b" & "bh" in the data source "Apex_Office_Time_Details" was the issue. When I deleted them the table worked. Then I tried renaming the fields to "Billed" & "Billable_Hours" and everything seems to be working

Comment: Hi Tom!  I'm not sure what the extraneous text in this question relates to your question.  If this is a quote from something, could you use quote text (see the top formatting bar when editing)?  In addition, could you change the placement of the links in the text so that context is understood for each link?

Comment: It looks like your question is formatted after the official issue reporter for App Maker. Since this Stack Overflow and not affiliated with Google or App Maker I would suggest getting rid of the extraneous text and reformatting your question so people have a better understanding of what is going on. Also, what you are describing sounds more like you are trying to create a relation vs an item under countries, if you can provide the actual code for the create button and it’s inherited datasource we may be able to better assist.

Comment: Sorry, I have revised my original post to be a bit more succinct. Also thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Success! Evidently there is a minimum length for the names in data sources. The number fields "b" & "bh" in the data source "Apex_Office_Time_Details" was the issue. When I deleted them the table worked. Then I tried renaming the fields to "Billed" & "Billable_Hours" and everything seems to be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success! Evidently there is a minimum length for the names in data sources. The number fields "b" & "bh" in the data source "Apex_Office_Time_Details" was the issue. When I deleted them the table worked. Then I tried renaming the fields to "Billed" & "Billable_Hours" and everything seems to be working